# How to add all the predictors at once and produce a logistic model against the response

Tags: r, combinations, addition

There are 780 predictors in my data set. I want to take the combination of all the predictors and use it to create the logistic model against response.

```
glm(response~ predictor1+predictor2+......+ predictor780, data=mnist_train, family=binomial(), maxit=100))
```

How to add all the predictors at once with a function and model against the response, without writing all the predictors' names and adding them?

Answer (score 4):

Another easy option is

```
glm(response~ ., data=mnist_train, family=binomial(), maxit=100))
```

Comment: One issue with this approach could be if they have other columns in the dataframe which they don't want to include.

Comment: Under such situation they have to do `subset()` first and then apply the model.

Comment: This code is for the model of response against each of the predictors separately. But I want to take the combination of the predictors by adding them and modeling them against the response.

Comment: OP said that there were 780 predictors in his dataset, no more and no less, thus Bappa's answer is appropriate.

Comment: @Sumit. By "combination", do you mean "interaction"? And both answers give a model that includes all predictors together, not separately.

Comment: Yes, interaction. Yeah, I know in general, all the predictors are taken, too. But the example I have given, I specified what I am looking for. By adding the predictors and modeling against response. That means the interaction among them.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `reformulate` with `paste0`

```
glm(reformulate(paste0('predictor', 1:780), "response"), 
    data=mnist_train, family=binomial(), maxit=100)
```

Comment: It shows the error - "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'predictor1' not found"

Comment: Is `predictor1` present in the dataframe `mnist_train` ?